# How to get BlogEngine.NET to run outside of a local environment?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, deployment, blogengine.net

I am trying to run BlogEngine.NET. It works fine locally in Visual Studio but whenever I publish it outside of my local computer none of the posts are showing up.

I think this is because none of the scripts or CSS are being loaded (the posts are done via AngularJS). I've made sure that the read and write permissions are allowed in IIS so I know that isn't the problem.

I believe that AngularJS isn't loading properly, as when I go to the admin panel the url returned with the 404 error is this:

```
8926/admin/%7B%7BSiteVars.RelativeWebRoot%7D%7Dadmin/#/dashboard
```

instead of:

```
8926/admin/#/dashboard
```

Even If I manually take out all of the `%7B%7BSiteVars.RelativeWebRoot%7D%7Dadmin` text, the posts still don't show up as they do locally which leads me to believe the posts are also tied to AngularJS as well.

Does anyone know how to fix this? This may not be a BlogEngine.NET problem as much as it is just a loading of Javascript and CSS problem inside of IIS

The documentation for my project is [here](https://blogengine.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

BlogEngine.Net had moved to GitHub that is where the latest updates are at.

Best to go here:

https://github.com/rxtur/BlogEngine.NET

and try again with a fresh install.

I have a fresh install working with no issues here:

http://blogengine07.azurewebsites.net

Took a total of around 30 mins to it it 100% up and running, creating new web app service,database, change web.config, publish to Azure, and making some changes in settings.

What web host are you using to host your website?

You can also try Azure Web App Service for free here:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/try/app-service/web/?language=cs

If you can get it to work there but not at your current web host then that points to a web server issue, since you are able to run it locally and on Azure.

Hope this helps.

Have a great Day!

Brian Keith Davis